# UICollectionView - 2 rows and equal spacing on each side

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to create layout in which I will have 2 items in each row and each item will have padding equal to spacing between items. eg - spacing between items must be equal to spacing between items and edges. I managed to get equal spacing between items horizontally, but vertically it's too big. How can I fix that ?

[image]

my code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width / 2 - 10, self.view.frame.width / 2 - 10 )
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has two properties:

- `minimumLineSpacing` "The minimum spacing to use between lines of items in the grid."
- `minimumInteritemSpacing` "The minimum spacing to use between items in the same row."

Tweak those two values and see what happens.